# SQL to PROC SQL- partition By alternative (min case)

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am new to SAS but know sql so trying to use SQL code to write `proc sql` code and realized that `PARTITION by` is not available in SAS.

Table

```
Customer_id Item_type   Order Size  Date        ….

 1. A401    Fruit           Small      3/14/2016    …. 
 2. A401    Fruit           Big        5/22/2016    …. 
 3. A401    Vegetable       Small      7/12/2016    ….
 4. B509    Vegetable       Small      3/25/2015    …. 
 5. B509    Vegetable       Big        3/15/2014    …. 
 6. B509    Vegetable       Small      3/1/2014     ….
```

Explanation

```
  Customer_id   Item_Type   Count       Reason
1.A401          Fruit       2           X-WRONG-because date corresponding  big item is later than others in group  
2.B509          Vegetable   2           RIGHT-Note that count is 2 only because one of the dates is earlier than the Big corresponding item(3/1/2014 is earlier than 3/15/2014)
```

SQL Output

```
  Customer_id   Item_Type   Count       
1.B509          Vegetable       2
```

```sql
select t.customer_id, t.item_type, count(*)
from (select t.*,
         min(case when OrderSize = 'Big' then date end) over (partition by customer_id, item_type) as min_big
  from t
 ) t
where date > min_big
group by t.customer_id, t.item_type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL dialects (MS Access, MySQL, SQLite, SAS' proc sql) that do not support window functions, most `PARTITION BY` calls can be replaced with correlated aggregate subqueries which is supported by all major SQL dialects. Consider the following adjustment:

```sql
select main.customer_id, main.item_type, count(*) as count
from 
   (select t.customer_id, t.item_type, t.date,
          (select min(case when OrderSize = 'Big' then date end) 
           from t sub
           where sub.customer_id = t.customer_id
           and sub.item_type = t.item_type) as min_big
    from t
   ) main
where main.date > main.min_big
group by main.customer_id, main.item_type;
```

Comment: Whoops! See edit. Add *date* in `SELECT` of derived table. Replacing your asterisk, I forget to include that important guy.